# install php-cassandra driver

Tags: drivers, php, ubuntu-16.04

have dependencies/naming issue:

```
sudo dpkg -i cassandra-cpp-driver_2.4.3-1_amd64.deb
```

returns

```
cassandra-cpp-driver depends on libuv; however:
  Package libuv is not installed.
```

`libuv` is installed but now it's called `libuv0.10` 
how "to explain" to the installer that `libuv = libuv0.10` ?

Can't build php-cassandra driver from source as well. But can build the cpp driver.

`pecl` install fails as well

Comment: Here is a list of pre-reqs for install `sudo apt-get install g++ make cmake libuv-dev libssl-dev libgmp-dev php php-dev openssl libpcre3-dev git`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, had to uninstall already installed libuv0.10 and libuv0.10-dev.

Then followed these instructions:

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear php5-dev libgmp-dev libpcre3-dev g++ make cmake libssl-dev openssl<br />
wget downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/ubuntu/14.04/dependencies/libuv/v1.8.0/libuv_1.8.0-1_amd64.deb<br />wget downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/ubuntu/14.04/dependencies/libuv/v1.8.0/libuv-dev_1.8.0-1_amd64.deb<br />
wget downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/ubuntu/14.04/cassandra/v2.4.2/cassandra-cpp-driver_2.4.2-1_amd64.deb<br />
wget downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/ubuntu/14.04/cassandra/v2.4.2/cassandra-cpp-driver-dev_2.4.2-1_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i libuv_1.8.0-1_amd64.deb<br />
sudo dpkg -i libuv-dev_1.8.0-1_amd64.deb<br />
sudo dpkg -i cassandra-cpp-driver_2.4.2-1_amd64.deb<br />
sudo dpkg -i cassandra-cpp-driver-dev_2.4.2-1_amd64.deb<br />

pecl install cassandra

ADD extension=cassandra.so in php.ini
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32997871/pecl-install-cassandra-throws-error-unable-to-load-libcassandra/38199275#38199275